# How do I restore console.log() function that has been disabled by a website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

UPDATED: The reason the console won't log is the site runs this script:

```
    // Production mode
    // Disable console.log
    console.log = function() {};
```

I'm guessing there isn't a way to get the function back on the site?

Prior issue:

I'm running a script in my Chrome console that follows everyone on a site. There are 200 people on the page, and I want to iterate through all the follow buttons and click them all by running this script in the console:

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-follow'); 
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) { 
inputs[i].click();
}
console.log("The btn-follow script has finished");
```

The script clicks the buttons fine but the log statement returns `undefined`.

Is there a way to log to the console from within the console?

When I try console.log directly it looks like this:

[image]

Here is what gets outputted when I type "console":

[image]

Comment: ummmm... what? What's wrong with `console.log`? I'm not sure this makes much sense

Comment: Just type "The btn-follow script has finished"

Comment: That *will* log to the console. After logging to the console, the console will display the return value (`undefined`). That doesn't prevent you looking at the previous line.

Comment: Just added an image - my example is simple but I wanted to use it to debug a much longer script, and if it doesn't log the outputs it's not much help with that.

Comment: @Quentin see above - the issue was this site disables the console.log function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can eliminate shadowed properties with `delete`:

```
delete console.log;
```

The original `log` function (which exists on `console`'s prototype) was never overwritten -- it has merely been shadowed by a property on the `console` instance. You can `delete` the instance function and let the original prototype function shine through.

Comment: Ha, didn't think about that. Nice! :)

Comment: Just for your information (this answer is Chrome oriented, so it is still valid):I've tried in in Firefox 40.0.3 and this solution does not work. The object `console`in Firefox is an Object with its own methods, there isn't a Console prototype to fallback if log is not defined

Comment: does not work anymore in chrome either.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm guessing there isn't a way to get the function back on the site?

Since you are using Chrome and can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), you can do:

```
var original_log = Object.getPrototypeOf(console).log;
```

The `log` method is defined on the prototype.

Comment: Unfortunately the prototype of console is showing up as an empty object on the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

[image: screenshot]

The log statement I submit (in blue) is followed by it's effect (the message, in black) and the return type of the log expression (in grey).

**EDIT**

Verify that you haven't replaced the console somehow. You can try the following:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried that but get the image I'm posting above - why is it different on my machine?

Comment: @YPCrumble, what version of Chrome are you using? Mine's 31.0.1650.63. I'm on Ubuntu 13.10, though I don't expect that to matter much.

Comment: Same on Mac - Chrome version 31.0.1650.63

Comment: @YPCrumble, I edited my answer. Please try the above. Maybe you've replaced your console object somehow.

Comment: @DrewNoakes Updated, looks like I get the same thing as you there.

Comment: @YPCrumble, crazy. Well, I'm out of ideas at this point! Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: thanks for your help - see my edit, the reason is that they have logs throughout the site and just disable the log function globally for production mode. Crazy!