# How to call original `console.log` that Chrome implements if it has been overriden by user's script?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

I'm debugging a website in Chrome's developer tools (F12) and the website's programmers have reimplemented `console.log` for their own purposes. In their code they've basically done this:

```
`console.log = function () { new code that has nothing to do with logging to console }`
```

When I call `console.log` it doesn't log to console.

My question is - how do I call the original `console.log` that the browser implements and not the overridden version?

I don't have access to website's code or its programmers.

Comment: You need to store a reference to the original `console.log` method before the override code is executed... then you can use that reference to call the original method

Comment: It's not my website and not my code, I can't store it.

Comment: then where are you writing your code

Comment: In the developer console (F12)

Comment: why not just delete those lines of codes for the console log?

Comment: @perseusl It's not my code. I'm debugging an existing website via developer tools.

Comment: You can use console.dir to effectively achieve the same result

Comment: You could just turn off javascript loading on that domain.

Comment: P.S.: in chrome dev tools you can edit the scripts as well..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore console.log() function that has been disabled by a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460685/how-do-i-restore-console-log-function-that-has-been-disabled-by-a-website)

Comment: try this `delete console.log;`

Comment: You can just try to use `console.info` instead in many cases.

Comment: `delete console.log` works :)

Comment: @MatteoTassinari The problem with that other question is that is related to Chrome; the answer does not work in Firefox, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the old implementation??

if not the most simple is to delete that old implementation

```
delete console.log;
```

It will automatically revert to default operation.

Comment: It worked! I dont need the old implementation. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey the OP is actually trying to get the old method.. not the overridden one.. So I do not see a point of this +1 vote here.. Who ever it was.. Please check

Comment: This answer does not work in Firefox 40, delete console.log removes everything as there is no prototype log method where to fallback. Actually `console.__proto__.constructor===Object`

Comment: @Pablo I'm using 40.0.3 and it works fine, if it doesn't work I think it is bugs in Firefox.